# Automatically hardlinking files, but only once

Tags: linux, bash, shell, automation

I have a script that runs every 30 minutes to find files matching a string and automatically hard-linking them to another folder. This folder then is uploaded to a backup and removed locally.

My current setup is working, but it inevitably hard-links the file again after it has been removed locally.

I am wanting to implement a way of logging what has already been linked, so when something is matched, it also checks against "hardlinklog.txt" file.

```
find . -name '*FILE*' -print0 | xargs -0 ln -t ~/media/
```

That is my current script with changed paths and filter.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a job for `grep -v -x -f hardlinklog.txt`

`-v`:  Pass only non-matching lines

`-f <file>`: Find the lines to check for in `<file>`

`-x`: Match entire lines only

Comment: Would this go between the two sections of my current script?

Comment: Binary file (standard input) matches is returned?